# Shwoing playernames with restriction

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.5

I have a question since I can't solve it myself.

I have, lets say a Player Class. (Multiplayer Game)

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, account_name, hide_name_settings=False):
        self.name = account_name
        hide_name = hide_name_settings
```

playerDict = {} #Pretty much where the class for each player is saved

So how could I get a player-list with "\n" after each, where hide_name is not True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, not like your class is currently defined. But if you change your code to this:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, account_name, hide_name=False):
        self.name = account_name
        self.hide_name = hide_name
```

Then it becomes trivial:

```
players = {0: Player('Sir Lancelot', True),
           1: Player('Sir Gallahad', False),
           2: Player('Sir Robin', True),
           3: Player('King Arthur', False),
           }

players_to_show = [players[k] for k in players if not players[k].hide_name]
for player in players_to_show:
    print(player.name)
```

---

Though honestly if I were trying to hide names, I'd probably do something like this:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, account_name, show_when_spectating=False):
        self.name = account_name
        self.show_when_spectating = show_when_spectating

spectators = [Player('Sir Lancelot', True),
           Player('Sir Gallahad', True),
           Player('Sir Robin', True),
           Player('King Arthur', False),
           ]
shown_spectators = [player for player in players if player.show_when_spectating]
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Tough its a bit hard to understand, but in my multiplayer game you can spectate other players, and player's can decide if they want to be shown as a spectator for the player or not. In the end it should be a spectator list, which lists every spectator in each line.

Comment: @Fragkiller I've updated my answer to show the approach that I would *actually* take.